# K-Size Subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, enumeration, subgraph

I need an algorithm to find k-size subgraphs of a large graph. What is your suggestion?

Note: My graph is undirected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you pick any k vertexes from a large graph you can make a sub-graph by selecting only those vertexes and the edges connecting them, if any.

If you want your k vertexes to be connected, you could pick k connected vertexes from a connected component of the large graph - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29

If you actually want k vertexes such that each vertex has an edge linking it to each of the other k-1 vertexes, then you need to know that this is called a clique, and finding this is a hard problem - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: Hi, my problem is a click problem. I would like to learn it's clear solution because I need it's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this is to perform a  [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)  or a  [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)  for K iteration.